# how to solve 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Tempo' in my case

Tags: python, tuples

For context, Tempo has temperature and 0 values and I am looking to create a counter in my dataframe. I saw some solutions for this problem online but I am afraid they are too complex for me to understand/implement.

This is my code:

```
prev_temp, cnt, n= -300, 0, 0

for row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Tempo!=0 and prev_temp==0:
        cnt+=1
        n+=1
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
    elif row.Tempo==0 and prev_temp!= 0:
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
```

The error I am getting is

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Tempo'

Comment: From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html): *"Iterate over DataFrame rows as __(index, Series)__ pairs."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `.iterrows()` returns tuple: **(index, Series)** (Series - is a row basically)

Try this snippet:

```
prev_temp, cnt, n= -300, 0, 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Tempo!=0 and prev_temp==0:
        cnt+=1
        n+=1
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
    elif row.Tempo==0 and prev_temp!= 0:
        prev_temp=rows.Tempo
```

So, in the example above I've replaced `for row in df.iterrows():` with `for index, row in df.iterrows():` in order to iterate over tuple items, not tuple itself.

By the way, I don't understand what are `rows` in your code standing for.

Comment: You're welcome. Please make sure marking that answer as correct if that helped.

Comment: Also, do you have any idea how I can have this counter displayed in my df as another column?